# How to remove the shutter at the opening and closing of the iPhone Camera in app?

Tags: iphone

I have to remove the shutter at the opening of the Camera. Is there any property regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are much better asked as 3 separate questions.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: I did. Now plz tell the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using `UIImagePickerController`. You have to use AVFoundation framework and access the camera from lower level.

Here's some (buggy) Apple sample code [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) to run and play with. However this code can be significantly simplified: [see this](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/).